# React native flexbox how to align items vertically?

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I'm a bit confused as to why this flex won't work.

```
 <View
style={{
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
}}
>
<View style={{ width: "40%", alignSelf: "flex-start" }}>
    <Button BUY</Button>
    <View style={{ alignSelf: "center", marginTop: "2%" }}>// A logo</View>
</View>
<View style={{ width: "40%", alignSelf: "flex-end" }}>
    <AreaChart
        style={{ height: 250 }}
        dataPoints={data}
        contentInset={{ top: 30, bottom: 30 }}
        curve={shape.curveNatural}
        svg={{
            fill: "rgba(134, 65, 244, 0.2)",
            stroke: "rgb(134, 65, 244)"
        }}
    />
</View>
</View>;
```

The intended layout I want to have is:

```
BUTTON  |   <CHART
LOGO    |   CHART>
```

The button and logos centered together, and the chart taking up both "boxes" on the right.

However, the above markup produces the following:

```
BUTTON |
LOGO   |
       | CHART
       | CHART
```

They're doing the right thing but the Chart starts where the logo ends.

Where did I go wrong with flexbox? How do I produce the right layout?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: We need the output HTML & CSS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the default `flexDirection` in React Native is `column`, flex items will stack vertically, hence the *chart* renders on a row of its own.

By using `alignSelf: "flex-end"` on the 2nd child `View`, which for `columns` control the cross axis (horizontal), it will right align.

To align them side-by-side, add `flexDirection: "row"` to the parent `View`.

*You can also remove both the `alignSelf` properties on the two child `View`'s, unless you want the 2nd `View` (`alignSelf: "flex-end"`) align to bottom.*

Updated code sample

```
<View style={{
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
}}>
    <View style={{width: "40%"}}>
        <Button
            BUY
        </Button>
        <View style={{alignSelf: "center", marginTop: "2%"}}>
            // A logo
        </View>
    </View>
    <View style={{ width: "40%"}}>
        <AreaChart
            style={{height: 250}}
            dataPoints={data}
            contentInset={{top: 30, bottom: 30}}
            curve={shape.curveNatural}
            svg={{
                fill: 'rgba(134, 65, 244, 0.2)',
                stroke: 'rgb(134, 65, 244)',
            }}
        />
    </View>
</View>
```